# Why is /etc/hosts file empty in my docker container?

Tags: docker

I created a minimal docker container, following https://github.com/snoyberg/haskell-scratch containing a single Haskell application. When run the application works fine except it cannot resolve hosts from `/etc/hosts` because it is empty which implies linking does not work correctly (or at  least I need to use numeric addresses which is impractical...).

I can see the file pointed at by `HostsPath` in container config is correctly populated but it seems it gets overwritten at some point when container starts.

docker version is 1.6.2 on Mac OS X Yosemite.

Container is built in several stages. First stage builds a container with a specially populated filesystem:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty  
MAINTAINER arnaud@capital-match.com

RUN apt-get install -qqy libgmp-dev netbase

ADD . /

RUN chmod +x /create_rootfs.sh
RUN /create_rootfs.sh
```

the `create_rootfs.sh` file contains the following:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 ROOTFS=/rootfs

 echo "Creating directories"

 mkdir -p /rootfs/bin
 mkdir -p /rootfs/lib
 mkdir /rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
 mkdir /rootfs/lib64
 mkdir -p /rootfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv
 # mkdir -p /rootfs/etc

 echo "Copying library files"

 cp -L /bin/sh /rootfs/bin/
 #cp -L /etc/protocols /rootfs/etc
 #cp -L /etc/services /rootfs/etc
 cp -L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
 cp -L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 /rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
 cp -L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 /rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
 cp -L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 /rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
 cp -L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 /rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
 cp -L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 /rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
 cp -L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 /rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
 cp -L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2 /rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
 cp -L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2 /rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
 cp -L /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 /rootfs/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
 cp -L /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /rootfs/lib64/
 cp -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/UTF-16.so /rootfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/
 cp -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/UTF-32.so /rootfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/
 cp -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/UTF-7.so /rootfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/
 cp -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules /rootfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/
 cp -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache /rootfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/
 cp -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 /rootfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Then I export the content of this filesystem building a

docker run capitalmatch/tinybuilder tar -cC /rootfs . | docker import - capitalmatch/tiny

The final container is built from "tiny", adding some `.tar.gz` files. It is then run as:

```
docker run --link stunnel:monitor capitalmatch/app
```

The `stunnel` container is run as:

```
docker run --name=stunnel -p 5555:5555 -v $(pwd)/stunnel:/etc/stunnel capitalmatch/stunnel
```

I expect `/etc/hosts` to contain an entry for `monitor` which is indeed the case before it is mounted. When I run another container built in a more "classical" way, e.g. based on `ubuntu:trusty, I found the`/etc/hosts` file to be correctly populated and everything works fine so I suspect it is the way the container is built that gets in the way.

Comment: how exactly looks first `run` call of container `stunnel`? `docker run --name stunnel ....`

Comment: done. Although I don't see how this is related to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an answer but I have a workaround: use

```
 FROM busybox
 ...
```

and everything works ok.

Answer (score 6):

`/etc/hosts` is regenerated every time base on how you run your container.

Moreover, if you put something into this file in Dockerfile... this will last till to end of building process of all layers, but will be wiped out when container will be started.

> **Editing networking config files**
>
> Starting with Docker v.1.2.0, you can now edit /etc/hosts, /etc/hostname and /etc/resolve.conf in a running container. This is useful if you need to install bind or other services that might override one of those files.
>
> Note, however, that changes to these files will not be saved by docker commit, nor will they be saved during docker run. That means they won't be saved in the image, nor will they persist when a container is restarted; they will only "stick" in a running container.
>
> source: https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#editing-networking-config-files

If your `/etc/hosts` file in your container doesn't contain expected entries, this means, that probably you not initialize container properly.

Please provide information how you actually run your containers or for simplification, just prepared `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question to add more info. I understand I must be doing something unexpected in the container but don't know why as it works fine except for those empty files.